# Oracle slow RANK function

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, rank, dense-rank

My application uses views that must be kept generic (no filters), and which include analytic functions `RANK` and `DENSE_RANK`.  For example I have a view `MYVIEW`:

```
SELECT 
RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY FIELD1 ORDER BY FIELD2) RANK, 
FIELD2, 
FIELD3
FROM TABLE1;
```

My application then applies the necessary filters at runtime i.e.

```
SELECT * FROM MYVIEW WHERE FIELD3 IN ('a','b','c');
```

My query is very fast without the RANK function, but painfully slow (2+ minutes) with it (I get the right results, just slow).  The underlying table has 250,000+ rows and I have no control over its design.  I cannot partition it any further.  So is it slow because it creates partitions for every unique entry in FIELD1 every time the view is called?  Any other way to avoid that?  Any suggestions on how to make this faster?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the query plans?

Comment: I woukd kind of expect it to apply the filter first (predicate pushing) and apply the ranking to the matching rows. But the execution plan will reveal what is going on. Do you get the rank values you expect - i.e. are they contiguous over the result set, or do they have gaps from being evaluated before the filter is applied? (And which do you want?)

Comment: @Alex Pole, predicate pushing for `FIELD3 IN ('a','b','c');` condition cannot work in this case, because this is kind of a materialized subquery:`SELECT ... FROM (subquery/view that numbers rows ) WHERE FIELD3 IN ('a','b','c');` - this query must first assign numbers to all rows, then pick some rows, but whithour changing the numbers. I guess that a simple multicolumn index on `table1(  FIELD1, FIELD2 )` can speed this query up.

Comment: @kordiko - my expectations are often wrong *8-) I wasn't sure if the ranking would always happen first (partly what I was asking) so you've saved me testing to find out.

Comment: Materialize the view? Don't know if that is possible since the RDBMS I'm working with doesn't allow analytic functions in materialized views. :(

Answer (score 1):

As was mentioned in the comments, with your analytic function in the view, Oracle can't take any shortcuts (predicate pushing) because

- in your view, you have created an agreement with Oracle: whenever the view is accessed the RANK should be based on all of the rows in the table - no WHERE clause was specified
- when querying a view, an "external" WHERE clause should never affect how a row generated by the view looks, but only whether or not that row is kept or not
- analytic functions look at other rows to generate a value so if you change those rows (filtering) you can change the value - pushing a predicate could easily affect the values generated by these functions
- if this could happen, your view result could become very inconsistent (just depending on how the optimizer chose to evaluate the query)

So, based on the details you've provided, your query needs to be evaluated like this:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM (
         SELECT
                RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY FIELD1 ORDER BY FIELD2) RANK, 
                FIELD2, 
                FIELD3
           FROM TABLE1
       ) myview
 WHERE <condition>; -- rankings are not affected by external conditions
```

and *not* this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
           RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY FIELD1 ORDER BY FIELD2) RANK, 
           FIELD2, 
           FIELD3
      FROM TABLE1
     WHERE FIELD3 IN ('a','b','c') -- ranking is affected by the conditions
)
```

So, is there a way to make this faster? Maybe.

1. If the table is partitioned, there's the thought of using parallel query.
2. Could an index help?

Not in the usual sense. Since there are no conditions in the view itself, it will do a full table scan to consider all of the rows for the rankings and by the time the WHERE clause is applied, it's too late to use an index for filtering.

However, if you had an index that "covered" the query, that is, have an index on just the columns being used (e.g. FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3 in that order), an index could be used as a smaller version of the table (instead of FULL TABLE SCAN the plan would show INDEX FAST FULL SCAN.) As a bonus, since it's already sorted, it could be efficient at working out the partitions on FIELD1 and then ordering on FIELD2 within each partition.

3. Another option would be to make this a materialized view instead, but if your data is changing often, it could be a pain to keep current.
4. One final thought would be something that is similar to the "poor man's" partitioning used before the days of the partitioning option.
   (Sorry I can't find a good link that describes this, but maybe you have heard of it before.)

*This is really only an option if:*

1. *your partitioning column has a relatively small number of distinct values*
2. *those values don't change*
3. *you know what partition values you can use to isolate the data on in your query*
4. *Oracle is willing to push the predicate when it's safe to do so*

Given that Oracle seems adverse to pushing the predicate when analytic functions are involved, I'm not giving this a high probability of success.

If you want more info on that, let me know.